# Unable to vote and comment on SU website

Tags: feature-request, superuser

Today I was reading a [SU answer](https://superuser.com/questions/218602/how-to-disable-openoffice-spell-checking) and I wanted to comment on it. I found out that "You must have 50 reputation to comment". Then I tried to vote and for my surprise I need 125 reputation to do that. I mainly use [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/), so I don't have reputation points on superuser website. However, I have a small reputation on SO, that should be considered here also. How am I suppose to add something to a question if I'm "blocked"? I know this question will be closed, downvoted, etc, but take this into consideration.

Comment: downvoting requires 125 reputation, 15 for upvoting

Comment: Cross-site related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215891/158100

Answer (score 3):

Each site is considered to be a community on its own and reputation [doesn't travel or get synced across sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215889/reputation-sync-across-sites). You do get an association bonus of 100 reputation if you have [200 reputation on any site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90712/158100).

If what you expected would be true you would also be able to vote on [DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) or [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/). Are you enough knowledgeable on those topics as well to cast votes?

To get enough reputation just suggest some edits, ask a good question or provide a well received answer. It is not that hard to gain 25 reputation....

See also [Six simple tips to get reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast).

Oh, and in case you forgot: [you spend 100 reputation on a bounty](https://superuser.com/users/124884/machineaddict?tab=reputation)

Comment: So you are saying that I should be an expert to comment or vote on a stack website? That's a complete nonsense. What if I find that answer good and I want to vote it? I'm not even given the option to be an "expert". The website assumes that I'm a newbie...

Comment: Tone it down will you... thanks.

Comment: The option you're given is to prove you're an expert. Do that and you will be good to go.

Comment: But how am I suppose to gain points, if the only way to do that is to ask a question?

Comment: I believe that already was in my answer but for your comfort I added another link....

Comment: @machineaddict see also: [How does a lurker gain reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164035/165773)

Comment: @rene: That is another "bug". If I already crossed the threshold required for a specific task, I should not be asked about reputation, even if it's lower. Anyway...

Comment: @machineaddict The behaviour might be a bit counter-intuitive in the case of bounties, but not in general. If you had dropped under the threshold because your posts were getting downvoted, then it would absolutely make sense that you'd have to re-earn the privileges you lost.